# Make a RESTful API Call to SharePoint Online from Console program

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, authentication

I knew how to make a `RESTful API` call to `SharePoint 2013 OnLine` from `SharePoint APP` (`Provided-Host App`). Like get `List` from `Site`. There are already many samples in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860569.aspx#Overviews).

Because the `TokenHelper` can handle the `OAuth` authentication for the `APP`. But I wondered If this can be made from a `C# Console Program`. If it can't be made by OAuth. Any other ways of Authentication? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use straight CSOM? You just need to set the `ClientContext.Credentials` property to a `SharePointOnlineCredentials` object.

Comment: Could you give me a sample code to help me more understanding ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand on which part? How to accomplish what you request with CSOM instead of REST? Or how to set the credentials?

Comment: I think what you mean is [this way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/02/23/call-o365-using-csom-with-a-console-application.aspx). Right ? thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the way I meant (needed to meet the minimum character count).

Comment: Thanks, But I think this way has a little bit tight coupling with SharePoint. Because of the reference CSOM dll libary. Right ? What I expect is just using HttpClient to make a RESTful call to SharePoint Online in loose coupling. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16891/discussion-between-wjervis-and-joe-wang).

Comment: Sorry for missing your comments because of the GFW. I accessed it with the VPN in my office which can pass through it . Now I was getting into the chat room.Found I can't send message in there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to consume SharePoint REST service using .NET you could consider the following approaches:

- [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) - Provides a base class for sending HTTP requests and receiving HTTP responses from a resource identified by a URI. (`.NET Framework 4.5`)
- [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) - provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI. (`.NET Framework 1.1`)
- [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) - provides an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class, more low-level then the previous ones

All of them allows to perform CRUD operations in SharePoint Online.

### About SharePoint Online authentication

Since SharePoint Online (SPO) uses claims based authentication, you could consider the following options:

- [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) as part of [SharePoint Online
  Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) provides credentials to access SharePoint
  Online resources.
- utilize a custom implementation, for example as explained in this [great
  article](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx)

### Example

The following example demonstrate how to retrieve List using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    public static JToken GetList(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials,string listTitle)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            var endpointUri = new Uri(webUri, string.Format("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{0}')", listTitle));
            var result = client.DownloadString(endpointUri);
            var t = JToken.Parse(result);
            return t["d"];
        }
    }
```

> Dependency: [Json.NET library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx)

Usage

The example demonstrates how to retrieve Contacts List and print its title:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var webUri = new Uri("https://contoso.sharepoint.com");
      const string userName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
      const string password = "password";
      var securePassword = new SecureString();
      foreach (var c in password)
      {
          securePassword.AppendChar(c);
      }
      var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

      var list = GetList(webUri,credentials,"Contacts");
      //print List title
      Console.WriteLine(list["Title"]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using any third party dll or Sharepoint SDK/ CSOM?

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh You can use System.Net.NetworkCredential or System.Net.CredentialCache (I usually just use DefaultCredentials for my purposes). If you prefer not to use JSON, you can put "application/atom+xml" in the Accept header and use XmlReader and System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Atom10FeedFormatter. Although, .Net does have built in JSON serialization.