# Consume sharepoint website with webapi

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, consumer

I developed Web app into with SharePoint designer using SharePoint online, so I have views, jquery calls to lists, etc. The problem is I can´t access SharePoint API like this  [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d6e32214-43a1-468c-942c-810e09dd9597/access-denied-app-part-on-anonymous-public-facing-site#cb100256-2bfd-4411-a54b-6ce9f490ee5e) say.

So my manager says that we need to do is to consume SharePoint app into VS web API to give credentials, I´m really new in Visual Studio, what will be my first steps?

> I open Visual studio --> New Project --> Web --> ASP.NET Web Application right?

So now what I need to do to do something like [these](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113929/make-a-restful-api-call-to-sharepoint-online-from-console-program) example?

I thing I need to right click solution -->new --> class ?

Help is very appreciated, sorry for basic questions

Answer (score 0):

No need of visual studio if you are using JSOM and Rest Api.
if it is sharepoint hosted app then you can use

```
SP.AppContextSite
```

to provide host Url and for example you can follow this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/updating-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api/)