# Call REST API from a console program OUTSIDE Sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to call a corporate Sharepoint REST API in order to retrieve a list data. When I use the browser I'm able to call the API (I use Restlet Client to test) provided I log first into the Sharepoint site.

I already succeeded to create a console program that asks me for the user/password by a second browser screen, but I'm looking for a solution that handles the http traffic necessary to authenticate automatically to the Sharepoint, without any human intervention.

This example ([Make a RESTful API Call to SharePoint Online from Console program](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113929/make-a-restful-api-call-to-sharepoint-online-from-console-program)) goes really close, but it fails with a "Data Encryption Key (DEK) has not been uploaded to the site" error.

Does anyone know how to connect directly into the Sharepoint REST API without having to install/configure anything in the Sharepoint server?

**PS:** It's an Office 365 Sharepoint site, and I have access only to a specific subsite.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris, it's an Office 365 Sharepoint for a big corporation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well SharePoint actually supports 'console programs' other than PowerShell...

But with PowerShell it does generally ask for a credentials input like you specified. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx

To automate this you would probably have to use CSOM, but check out the PnP SAML/ CSOM solution here

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/SAML%20authentication.md

Or [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651218/login-to-sharepoint-automatically) over on stack overflow