# how to use sharepoint rest api with C#?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to use C# to get listitems from sharepoint online (i cannot use sharepoint.client.dll because the tools doesn't support it), hence i looking for other way like http get/ post by sharepoint rest api. the following code return 403 but it should be success. Any idea?

```
            try
        {
            var username = "xxx@company.com";
            var password = "P@ssword";

            var domain = "company.sharepoint.com";
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");//we want to receive JSON rather than XML

            var response = await client.GetAsync("_api/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items");
            var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                lbl_result.Text += content;

            }else{
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                lbl_result.Text += content;

            }
        }catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_result.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials` instead of `System.Net.NetworkCredential`. Here's an example:

```
var siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com";

var username = "user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "pass@word1";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(c => securePassword.AppendChar(c));
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = credentials;

var uri = new Uri(siteUrl);
handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

var json = string.Empty;
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    var response = await client.GetAsync(siteUrl + "/_api/Web");

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

403 is "forbidden", so an issue with credentials. In SharePoint online you need to be authenticated. See this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints and do a search for "c# rest api sharepoint online 403" for examples.

This looks like a good example: [Make a RESTful API Call to SharePoint Online from Console program](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113929/make-a-restful-api-call-to-sharepoint-online-from-console-program)

Comment: hi, i found that most of calling rest api example are using sharepoint client dll. This dll is not supported in my developing tool. Is there any way to make a rest api with credentials?

Comment: @kingyau   Using the REST API does not require any client DLL. It's just a URL to a resource. Data is sent and returned in XML or JSON format. What you saw was probably using a DLL to get the credentials. I'll look around and see if I can find a better example for you.