# SharePoint access via API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, api

I have just started with a SharePoint and I am not able to do a simple thing.

I have over 12k files on SharePoint and I want to write a desktop app using C#, which schows me all files with names, sizes, paths and modification dates. Then user can select and download few of them. App schould work in an external network.

I tried with a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and REST Api but I always got 403 Access Forbidden.

Is it even possible to download this informations from external network? If it is, which API schould I use? I'am little bit confused in SharePoint world.

SharePoint is with O365 and cliens are external customers, so they won't have any accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have two issues to deal with: permissions, and list throttling limits. For a start on authorization do a search for "sharepoint online rest api c#" or start here: [Make a RESTful API Call to SharePoint Online from Console program](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113929/make-a-restful-api-call-to-sharepoint-online-from-console-program)

When working with large lists, you will need to make multiple requests to page through the results, typically no more than 5,000 at a time.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I found following dll: microsoft.sharepoint online.csom. It works and it's fine. But now I am stuck. I have to share all my files, which means I have to generate anonymous view link for them. ObjectSharingInformation.anonymousViewLink returns this link only if I manually click on specific file and share it. It doesn't work if I share whole folder. Is it possible to generate anonymous link for all files? I don't have method ctx.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument in my dll.