# SPFx calls blocked by CORS policy

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, sharepoint-framework, cors

I'v been trying to access various apis through SPFx and I am constantly seeing this issue. I do not know how to fix this can anyone assist or explain what I am doing wrong or missing?

This works perfectly fine with `$.getJSON("https://www.mindicador.cl/api").then(console.log)`

> workbench.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://www.mindicador.cl/api'
>   from origin 'https://localhost:4321' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

My function:

```
  private makeRequest(): Promise<HttpClientResponse> {
        const url = `https://www.mindicador.cl/api`;

        const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();

        requestHeaders.append("Content-type", "application/json");
        requestHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
        requestHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
            headers: requestHeaders,
            method: "GET"
        };

        return this.context.httpClient
            .get(url, HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            });
    }
```

Comment: SharePoint by default does not allows the incoming requests from other origin. Please refer my answer and follow the steps. Hope that would help.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240189/how-to-use-sharepoint-rest-api-in-an-application-that-is-hosted-outside-of-share/240333#240333

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between jquery call and the native `httclient` call is a method of making http asynchronous request.
jquery uses old good xhr, but `httpclient` uses modern [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). When making CORS request with fetch API sometimes browser sends preflight request to understand server CORS possibilities (which origins are accepted, which headers, etc.). Your service, `https://www.mindicador.cl/api` doesn't support preflight requests, that's the reason why it fails.

The good news is that it's possible to remove preflight request under certain conditions. You can read more in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30296149/434967):

> To disable the OPTIONS request, below conditions must be satisfied for ajax request:
>       Request does not set custom HTTP headers like 'application/xml' or 'application/json' etc
>       The request method has to be one of GET, HEAD or POST. If POST, content type should be one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain

Which means that you should remove all custom headers to make it work:

```
const url = `https://www.mindicador.cl/api`;

const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: new Headers(),
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors"
};

this.context.httpClient
    .get(url, HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    });
```

Comment: Hey Sergei, this helped. The solution was to remove the headers. However, I can't make post requests to this api (https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-10-keeping-up-with-the-jsons) and the instructions directly state I need to pass in certain headers in order for JSON to be read by the API using fetch. I've used Axios (XHR) and it works for my POST requests but I can't use the SPFx HttpClient to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's all because SPFx uses Fetch API, which sometimes requires preflight (`OPTIONS`) request prior actual http call. I think the only option for you is to go ahead with xhr (axios, jquery, etc.)

Comment: Based on the link I provided, for POST you can't set json content-type

Comment: Oh okay. Is this normal? I would think that SPFx webparts would be a great opportunity to create elements that access 3rd party APIs, which I wouldn't consider out of the norm for SharePoint sites, but it seems very challenging to achieve this. Most examples I see are related to Graph, Azure or SP calls but nothing with 3rd parties.

Comment: That's absolutely normal. If Fetch API doesn't work for you, just use an alternative.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification and help Sergei.