# Issue with rendering XML data in SPFx

Tags: spfx, react, rss, typescript

I am in a project of making a RSS feed in SPFx and using React.js and TypeScript.

When I try to retrieve XML data from a news site, the console gives error:

[image]

Because it complains about CORS, so I tried using a CORS extension in Chrome and enable CORS but the I get these errors:

[image: When enabling CORS]

The code looks like this for my attempts to fetch an XML page from a Swedish news site:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import styles from '../RssApp.module.scss';
import { IRssAppProps } from './IRssAppProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import {IRssAppState} from './IRssAppState'

export default class RssApp extends React.Component<IRssAppProps, IRssAppState> {
  constructor(props: IRssAppProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

        title: 'afton',
        link: ''

    }
  }

  private async FetchDataFromXml(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = () =>{
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var myXML = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
          this.setState({

              title: myXML.items[i].title,
              link: myXML.items[i].link

          });
        }
      }
    }
    request.open("GET", "https://www.aftonbladet.se/nyheter/rss.xml", true)
    request.send();
    //console.log(this.FetchDataFromXml);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    {this.FetchDataFromXml()}
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IRssAppProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.rssApp }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>{this.state.title}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And nothing except my hard coded step "afton" is showing in the webpart.
Would apprieciate of someone could help me. Is there another way  to solve this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the SPFx httpclient. You can refer to a similar issue here : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254050/spfx-calls-blocked-by-cors-policy