# Problem making 3rd party API POST calls using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, api, cors

I need to fetch few details from the 3rd party API so I am making a POST request (required by the API) to that API using HttpClient But every time I am getting the below error.

`Access to fetch at 'https://3rd-party API url' from origin 'https://localhost:4321' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` and then it simply returns invalid token error.

Below is my code :

```
import { HttpClient, IHttpClientOptions, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

  private getDetails(jwt_token: string): Promise<HttpClientResponse> {

    let postURL = "https://3rd-party API url";

    const bodyJson = JSON.stringify({
        //json to fetch
    });

    let bearer = "Bearer " + jwt_token;

    const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.append('Authorization', bearer);
    requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');  

    const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
      body: bodyJson,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      mode: 'cors',
      // method: 'POST',
      // redirect: 'follow'
    };

    return this.props.HttpClient.post(
      postURL,
      HttpClient.configurations.v1,
      httpClientOptions)
      .then((response): Promise<HttpClientResponse> => {
        //Here it throws error
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        debugger;
        return jsonResponse;
      }) as Promise<any>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDetails(accessToken));
  }
```

I have tried to set the below extra headers apart from the mandatory Content-Type & Authorization headers (required by the API):

```
requestHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
requestHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
requestHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
```

Same error occurs when I run this from the hosted workbench.

It just works fine with the Postman and returns result without even mentioning these headers. Is there anything extra do I need to add to fetch the results from third party API ? Thanks

Comment: This [SP.SE question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/254050/20540) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Naveen. Already have been through this answer, It did not provide any solution in my case.

Comment: Did your issue fixed?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey not yet. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Try it on SharePoint web part page, instead of localhost.

Comment: Already tried. Same issue.

Comment: can u call your 3rd party API from Postman? Generic solutions for these types of issues are to configure the API(In your case the 3rd Party one) as CORS enabled. And if the 3rd party API owner is concerned about the security and the openness of the API, they can specify your SahrePoint Tannent in the CORS enable list.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace mode with no-cors,

```
const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
      body: body,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      mode: 'no-cors'
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to make POST request to external API. External API must be configured to accept CORS requests.

```
public externalAPIpost (): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            const body: string = JSON.stringify({
                'body': YOURBODY
            });
            const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': YOUR ORIGIN,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Method': 'POST',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
                    'Origin': YOUR ORIGIN,
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${my_access_token}`
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: body
            };
            const endpoint: string = ENDPOINT URL;

            this.HttpClient.post(endpoint, HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)
                .then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response;
                    } else {
                        reject(this.getErrorMessage(response));
                    }
                })
                .then((respData) => {
                    resolve(respData);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(this.getErrorMessage(error));
                });
        });
    }
private getErrorMessage(error: any): string {
        console.log (error);
        const errorMessage: string = error.errorMessage ? error.errorMessage : error;
        return errorMessage;
    }
```