# What are the required modifications in web.config in sharepoint site to expose URL to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery-ajax, sharepiont

I'm new to working with sharepoint. When i tried to call share point API url from ajax call in JavaScript. But, it's continuously failing and throws the error. I can say, that is CORS error. So, i've made changes in web.config like below.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept,X- FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED,crossDomain,credentials " />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

and ajax call as below

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var items = data.d;
                console.log("Login Name: " + items.LoginName);
                console.log("Email: " + items.Email);
                console.log("ID: " + items.Id);
                console.log("Title: " + items.Title);
            },
            error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqxr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Please help me regarding this. I'm trying since 2 days.

> Update:

This error I'm getting.

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: Are you calling the SharePoint API from application outside SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, I mean the html page is not in the same site(IIS site) where SharePoint site is actually hosted.

Comment: Did you restarted the IIS site (the one you changed in web.config) ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question. I've added the error which i'm getting. I can understand the error. But, i don't know what to do to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Access control allow origin settings in web.config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:62747" />
```

As the error states, you shouldn't use the wildcard. Use the application url.

**Edit**: (Fix for Data will not come via ajax call but you can see under response in Network tab)

Disable the **Request Management** service on the SharePoint server. Following are the steps to do it.

Go to

1. Central Admin Application Management
2. Manage services on server (under    Service Applications)
3. and Stop the Request Management service.

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240189/how-to-use-sharepoint-rest-api-in-an-application-that-is-hosted-outside-of-share)

Comment: Sure, i'll try and let you know. Please i'm requesting you to be available. Thanks.

Comment: @Chanikya Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you.

Comment: Can i give my HTML file path instead of 'https://localhost:62747'. Like 'E:/Folder/test.html' this is my path.

Comment: @Chanikya You can try that or else you can open the html in visual studio that will generate a http local host url.

Comment: Yah i know VS can call IIS Express. But, the problem is client system has no visualstudio. Anyway your suggestion is worked for me. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Actually data is coming in form of XML. I can see it when SP url paste in chrome. But, I couldn't able to see the data in ajax call. Is there any modifications do i need to to ajax call?

Comment: @Chanikya I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail Shaikh